# I can read iframe's object, but I can't modify it's CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am using Google Forms, get an  and then I embed into my website code,

I want to custom the form's background, make it transparent.

I am using JQuery,It can read the object create by iframe from google, but if I want to change its class 'ss-form-container's css, it failed.

Can someone show me how to apply CSS to google docs's iframe?

Here is the Link to my test website: http://dive.maxinrui.com/    The questionary is on third slide.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Frames are not allowed to interact with each other unless they have the same origin. Since the origin of the Google Docs frame is `docs.google.com` while your page's main frame is on `dive.maxinrui.com`, you cannot "touch" the contents of the frame, so there is no way for you to apply your CSS to it.

You can apply some styling to a Google Docs form by applying a theme to it in Docs. If you need more control than that, though, you will need to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a workaround solution (if it works).

Would it be viable to copy the form source code from the Google Docs page in the iframe, embed it into your own page, then modify the CSS?